# PostgreSQL: UPDATE row if exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need update row in the table only if row exists.

```
UPDATE table1 SET ctime = now() WHERE id = 112233;
```

Or with `select` before

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE id = 112233) THEN
   UPDATE table1 SET ctime = now() WHERE id = 112233;
END IF;
```

Which query better to reduce write operations?

For performance purpose, do I need to do SELECT before UPDATE to check row exists?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This query:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET ctime = now()
    WHERE id = 112233;
```

Does exactly what you want.  It updates all rows that match the `WHERE` condition -- over zero rows.

If you are concerned about performance, create an index on `table1(id)`.  If `id` is a primary key, then it already has an index.

Comment: plus, it will return the count of rows changed, so you can see if update actually updated something... if you care.